# about local storage.getItem()

Tags: javascript, api

I'm a new learner for API, and I have a quesion about local storage. This is a code example from my javascript book:

```
if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
  var txtUsername = document.getElementById('username'); 
  var txtAnswer = document.getElementById('answer');

  txtUsername.value = localStorage.getItem('username');  
  txtAnswer.value = localStorage.getItem('answer');      

  txtUsername.addEventListener('input', function () {   
    localStorage.setItem('username', txtUsername.value);
  }, false);

  txtAnswer.addEventListener('input', function () {   
    localStorage.setItem('answer', txtAnswer.value); }, false);
  }
}
```

I want to ask why should we "localStorage.getItem()" part? Cause I think if user type their username, then we can get their names just from the variable "txtUsername" cause I thought it should be setItem first and then getItem. Thank you!

Comment: because when you want to remember username and answer after reloading or reopening the browser. Example: when an user has already entered username and answer and left your site, then you can fill out input-fields automatically when they come back.

Comment: I know that is the reason why we use local storage. But I confused if we haven't tried to setItem(), how can we use getItem()?

Comment: when you use getitem its returns undefined simply, if you have not used setitem for a certain key before.

Comment: So, If the browser hasn't stored the username before, it will update and store it. If the browser has stored this username before, then it will fill the input automatically.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Local storage is used to store small amounts of data on the client side. What does your code ?!

**For example:** A user visited the site for the first time and complete the inputs, , the data stored in the local store. The user closed the browser. The next day he again went to the site to fill out the form again, and its data is already filled. Conveniently!

Also we can use local storage as js object

```
txtUsername.value = localStorage.getItem('username');  
txtUsername.value = localStorage.username;
txtUsername.value = localStorage['username'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, it works just as you said.

It's just, when person types data in the textbox he uses setItem - that what 'input' eventListener used for

Think of LocalStorage as of really light database that keeps data even when user closes the page

But since it can store data when page is closed, you want to show the content of it in the textbox - and that's why author uses 'getItem' on start